# How can I clear the input in a gradio app automatically?

Tags: python, gradio

I want to be able to clear the input with gradio at the end of completing the inference without any additional click from the user.  Currently with live=True, the inference function is triggered when the recording is stopped.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
audio_input = gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath")
demo = gr.Interface(
    fn=inference, 
    inputs=audio_input,
    outputs="text",
    live=True
)
demo.launch()
```

- I tried re-initializing the audio component at the end of my inference function.  That didn't change anything
- I looked through the docs related to components and all examples I found for other components and couldn't find anything to do this.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Found on [Gradio doc](https://gradio.app/docs/#image) for image component but there is also mention of audio component.

```
def clear():
  audio_input.clear()

clear_btn = gr.Button(value="Clear")
clear_btn.click(clear, [], [])
```

[Gradio docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xtRW.png)

### solution 2

```
def clear():
  return None

clear_btn = gr.Button(value="Clear")
clear_btn.click(clear, inputs=[], outputs=[audio_input])
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to solve a similar problem. Please see I've use:

```
audio=gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath",label='️', interactive=True) 

.then(lambda:None, None, audio, queue=False) #here clean up passing None to audio.
```

See the full code below. Could anyone help improve it? I made comments and use the .then as I did seem not so good.

```
import gradio as gr
import os
import time
from AppChatBot import main
from custom_actions import recog


history = []

title = '  AI ASSISTANT'  
description="""An AI Bot app uses with WebSearch, Weather Forecast, Chat with your PDF."""

def add_text(history, text):
    history = history + [(text, None)]
    return history, gr.update(value="", interactive=False)

def receivaudio(pathaudio):
    textaud = recog(pathaudio) #function calls gTTs speach_recognizer
    history.append((textaud, None)) #appending the text to the history due not to change the bot function 
    return textaud

def bot(history):
    history[-1][1] = "" #by gradio example
    mens = history[len(history)-1][0] #workaround
    response = main(mens) #main function that call openAI chatbot with functions calling
    
    for character in response:  #streaming text caracter
        history[-1][1] += character
        time.sleep(0.03)
        yield history

with gr.Blocks(theme=gr.themes.Soft()) as demo:
    gr.Markdown(f'<center><h3>{title}</h3></center>')
    gr.Markdown(f'<center>{description}</center>')

    with gr.Group():

        chatbot = gr.Chatbot(
            [],
            elem_id="chatbot",
            bubble_full_width=False,
            avatar_images=(None, (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "robot.gif"))),
        )

    with gr.Row():
        txt = gr.Textbox(
            scale=4,
            show_label=False,
            placeholder="Enter text and press enter, or record an audio",
            container=True,
            autofocus=True,
        )
        audio=gr.Audio(source="microphone", type="filepath",label='️', interactive=True) #included audio
        
    txt_msg = txt.submit(add_text, [chatbot, txt], [chatbot, txt], queue=False).then(
        bot, chatbot, chatbot
    )
    txt_msg.then(lambda: gr.update(interactive=True), None, [txt], queue=False) # the gradio chat example ends here
    
    # I have coding this part to add the audio. note the sequences of "then"
    audio.stop_recording( receivaudio , inputs=audio, outputs=txt, queue=False).then(
        add_text, [chatbot, txt], [chatbot, txt], queue=False).then(
            lambda: gr.update(interactive=True), None, [txt], queue=False).then(
                bot, chatbot, chatbot).then(lambda:None, None, audio, queue=False)
    
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo.queue()
    demo.launch()
```